# How to build Java Web application having servlet v. 2.4 and JSP v 2.0 using Ant?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ant, war

First of all, I am an absolute noob in Java web applications.
So I apologise if my question looks silly.

I have to build Java Web application as a WAR file from source.
It should have Servlet version: 2.4 and JSP version: 2.0, and not greater.

For example, if I build it on Netbeans 7, I get it with Servlet version 3.0 and JSP version 2.1 - not what I need. So to get it built with older versions I have to use Netbeans 5.5 with JRE 1.5.0 installed.
But this method is totally awkward.

Can I use Ant (or maybe Maven) for the purpose, and how?

Comment: You can configure the servlet version you want to use in your web.xml file

Comment: You could use maven to compile and build your war. What do you want to use ant for?

Comment: Rob, I have this line in my web.xml: `<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">`

Is it that? When in Netbeans 7, it has no effect on servlet version.

Comment: Yes, I want to compile and build WAR file.